# как узнать, какая веб-страница вызывает внешний скрипт javascript

Tags: javascript

как узнать, какая веб-страница вызывает внешний скрипт javascript? Мне необходимо отслеживать, кто использовал мой JavaScript используя прямую ссылку на мой сервер domen.ru/script.js

Answer (score 1):

По моему, ответ очевиден:

Вы можете отслеживать обращения к Вашему серверу, анализируя его логи.

Если быть более конкретным, то, например, для nginx *свежие* логи находятся - по умолчанию - в `/var/log/nginx/access.log.1`

Пример записей из лога:

```
    77.246.237.74 - - [22/Oct/2021:15:38:06 +0300] "GET /style/index.css HTTP/1.1" 200 9093 "https://maket1.junecat.ru/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36"
    77.246.237.74 - - [22/Oct/2021:15:38:06 +0300] "GET /image/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 77710 "https://maket1.junecat.ru/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36"
    77.246.237.74 - - [22/Oct/2021:15:38:06 +0300] "GET /index.js HTTP/1.1" 200 135 "https://maket1.junecat.ru/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36"
    77.246.237.74 - - [22/Oct/2021:15:38:06 +0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "https://maket1.junecat.ru/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36"
```

Как раз в третьей строке лога Вы видите запрос к скрипту.

Вам достаточно проанализировать обращения к серверу и вытащить из файла все строчки, в котрых упоминается Ваш js - скрипт.

Обратите внимание, что, вообще, полезно посмотреть в директорию логов - в моём случае это `/var/log/nginx/`, потому, что еще там содержится файл `error.log.1` - там содержатся ошибки, которые возникли при обращениии к веб-серверу, а на них тоже иногда интересно поглядывать. Например, видно, как боты приходят его ломать стандартными способами.

**Дополнение**

у Вас есть много способов взаимодействовать с логами. Например, можно ссделать REST - сервис, который будет аргументом принимать промежуток времени и имя скрипта, а результатом выводить кол-во вхождений скрипта в файл. Если это то, что Вам нужно - напишите в комментариях, я вечерком попробую набросать такой REST - сервис

Comment: О, спасибо большое. А не подскажите, возможно ли как-нибудь взаимодействовать с логами? Ну, например, чтобы строки логов с использованием JS вытягивались и выводились в HTML?

Comment: Я дополнил ответ, можете глянуть. Ну, и напишите, этого ли Вы хотите

Comment: Спасибо еще раз большое за ответ)
Ну да, по сути оно и нужно, просто в JS никогда не залазил, вот как с пару дней от необходимости залез. Я посмотрел логи, там не отображается, какой домен использует мой JS
Сколько не искал ответа на РУ просторах и US просторах, не нашел ничего
Хотелось бы отслеживать именно какой домен использует мой JS по ссылке

Comment: у Вас в логах будет IP - адрес, с которого произошел запрос скрипта. Этого достатчоно?